# Xcode 6 archive AdHoc distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, ad-hoc-distribution

With Xcode 6 I can't export `ipa` and `plist` like in Xcode 5 when export for AdHoc.
Now Xcode only export an `ipa` without `plist`, so I can't upload `plist` on server and redirect my customer to my web site for download the app just from the device.

In addiction to this, I have setup an app to receive push notification, exported as AdHoc distribution (without `plist`) and uploaded to my web site using an old plist, but when I open the app for the first time, doesn't ask the classic question "App would send push notification...".

So, the question is: How is the new correct procedure to distribute app to tester in ad hoc distribution ? I know on iOS 8 I can use testflight, but in iOS 7 how can I do the same thing that just until a week ago work perfectly ?

Comment: I've been using the old plist from Xcode 5 - just leave it in-place on the server. I haven't seen the push issue, though.

Comment: notifications on iOS 8 have changed and you should now request permissions in a different way. Check the docs.